# npm install not installing latest version on GitHub

Tags: node.js, express, npm, sails.js, waterline

I have a module called 'sails-mongo' and I want to update it to the newest version using the following command:

```
npm update sails-mongo --save
```

I also tried uninstall then install again. I tried `sails-mongo@latest` and `sails-mongo@beta`.

**Problem**:
The current version (**master**) on GitHub the package.json (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/package.json) file has:

```
"dependencies": {
  "async": "~0.2.9",
  "lodash": "~2.4.1",
  "mongodb": "1.4.2",
  "waterline-errors": "~0.10.0"
},
```

And in the one being updated

```
"dependencies": {
  "async": "0.2.10",
  "underscore": "1.5.2",
  "underscore.string": "2.3.3",
  "mongodb": "~1.3.23"
},
```

The only way I get the master branch is using the command `npm install git+https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo`

**Why doesn't `sails-mongo@latest` install the master branch?**

Comment: Because NPM doesn't install from Github, it installs from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sails). The `repository` key in `package.json` just identifies a repository which shows on the NPM page.

Comment: +1 but not sure I got you, let me ask it differently: how does NPM know which version to install?

Comment: Packages are published to NPM independently of Github. When a developer publishes the package, it takes the version number from `package.json`. NPM stores each of these almost like Github does. When you run NPM install <package> it will always install the latest version, but if you specify the package in `package.json` you can add which version you'd like to install.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By default, NPM dependencies are pulled from the NPM repository. Authors must manually upload new versions of their software to the NPM repository, so the "`@latest`" version of the code hosted on NPM is different from the latest version of the code that exists anywhere (e.g., on GitHub).

According to the NPM repository's [info page on Sails](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sails), the latest NPM-hosted version is `0.9.16` while the [current GitHub version](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/b9cdce9a485b17b2fde8b34dfa8a480f49c220cb/package.json) is `0.10.0-rc3`.

If you want to have your project depend upon a particular branch or commit of a particular Git repo (instead of the version(s) hosted on the NPM repository), the NPM developers have included an explicit mechanism to allow this, detailed in "[Git URLs as Dependencies](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies)" in the [`package.json` docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html):

> **Git URLs as Dependencies**
>
> Git urls can be of the form:
>
> ```
> git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
> git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
> git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
> git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
> git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
> ```
>
> The `commit-ish` can be any tag, sha, or branch which can be supplied as an argument to `git checkout`. The default is `master`.

In fact, it's easier still to [use a Github.com repo](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#GitHub-URLs) as a dependency:

> As of version 1.1.65, you can refer to GitHub urls as just `"foo": "user/foo-project"`. For example:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "foo",
>   "version": "0.0.0",
>   "dependencies": {
>     "express": "visionmedia/express"
>   }
> }
> ```

So, to use the Sails GitHub repo, simply use:

```
"dependencies": {
  "sails": "balderdashy/sails-mongo",
  ...
}
```

And to use the exact state of Sails as it exists on GitHub as of April 28, 2014, use:

```
"dependencies": {
  "sails": "git://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo#b9cdce9a48",
  ...
}
```

Comment: So there is actually no way to install ```latest stable``` release without going to github everytime and specifically check which release/branch/etc. you need?

Comment: @Andrey Can you not just use the repo's master branch for the latest stable version? If the repo maintainers keep making new branches and switching which branch has the latest version, then yes, you'd need to keep up with that maintainer's shell-game of which branch is latest.

Comment: Not always, i.e. ```npm install github:jquery/jquery-ui``` installs latest available release (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/releases)...

Comment: @Andrey Interesting! That behavior does not need to be documented anywhere I've seen. (The page I linked to when writing this answer last year has disappeared, and I don't think it said anything about releases back then.) I'm not sure when npm uses releases vs. master. (If you can find it, that would make a great addition or possibly separate answer. If you can't find anything, it might make a good separate *question*.)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.  Via the NPM Registry I was trying to get the latest from a project I saw in in GitHub, like this:

```
//package.json
"devDependencies": {
    "foo-package": "^3.3.0",
}
```

But the code I got back from `npm install` (as observed in the `node_modules/` folder) was not what I saw in GitHub repository's master branch.  I was confused; as the two didn't match.

I eventually found: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view, which reveals some information (versions and dates) of what the NPM Registry is aware of for a particular repository.

```
// Console example
npm view foo-package
```

After confirming that what I wanted from GitHub repository's master branch wasn't in the NPM Registry, I eventually changed my approach  [Git URLs as Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), just as @apsillers answers.

Comment: What is an extra info in your answer additionally to @apsillers answer?

Comment: It's been 2+ years since I wrote this.  However, it appears the value added to @apsillers answer is the *debugging tool* toward understanding what is published on npm.

Hence the tool: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view