# Use pull request before it has been merged to the main branch

Tags: angular, github, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using [**this ionic cache service**](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache) module, but it as some savior bug.
You can see [**it here (issue 42)**](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache/issues/42).

I can see a [pull request to that bug too](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache/pull/43). Yet, it is not merged into the main branch.

Can you tell me how to use that fix with my `Ionic 3` app?

**Update:**

I have tried `npm i --save Nodonisko/ionic-cache#pull/43/head`as mentioned below answer by **@VonC**.But the problem here is when I used `npm i --save Nodonisko/ionic-cache#pull/43/head`,it removes `dist` folder inside the `node_modules/ionic-cache`.Then no api details for the package and it is not working.Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install from github pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181297/npm-install-from-github-pull-request)

Answer (score -2):

If you have clone the [`Nodonisko/ionic-cache`](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache) repo locally, you can apply this pull request, even though it is not yet merged into master.
See "[How to apply a git patch when given a pull number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235040/6309)":

```
git checkout -b mylocalbranch
git pull origin pull/43/head
```

But since you used npm install, see "[npm install from github pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33181297/6309)":

```
npm install <user>/<repo>#pull/<id>/head
```

In your case:

```
npm i --save-dev Nodonisko/ionic-cache#pull/43/head
```

Comment: OK, I'll do that step.But after that how can I use it with my ionic app? Because I have installed it like this `npm install ionic-cache @ionic/storage --save`.So how can I do that step then?

Comment: Oh..Is that mean I just need to run this cmd only? `npm i --save-dev Nodonisko/ionic-cache#pull/43/head`

Comment: @Sampath Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: I have done that step.After that, it put new entry on `package.json` file as like `"ionic-cache": "github:nodonisko/ionic-cache#pull/43/head",` under the `devDependencies`.Earlier no such entry.Only under `dependencies` like this `"ionic-cache": "^2.0.4",`.That entry still there.But the problem now is app says `[ts] Cannot find module 'ionic-cache'. on this `import { CacheModule } from "ionic-cache";`.Can you tell me what need to do now?

Comment: @Sampath The PR would represent master+a patch, not 2.0.4, so you need to adjust your dependencies. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23348036/6309

Comment: Is that mean do I need to do like this on `package.json` under `dependencies` section `"ionic-cache": "github:nodonisko/ionic-cache#pull/43/head",`? After that do I need to run `npm i` again?

Comment: @Sampath I suppose so, but I haven't try it: If it does not work, try and see what SHA1 your installed git repo is (with the applied path), and use that SHA1 instead.

Comment: I have done this `"ionic-cache": "git://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache#6105ebacbb70e67bef2866bb5a31c2d83736b876",` and after that run `npm i` as a fresh install.The problem here is, it doesn't install any source code of the api. Just an empty folder and having `licens/redme/package` under the `node_modules/ionic-cache`.Hope you have a solution?

Comment: @Sampath I don't have anything more than my previous link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23348036/6309. I can read it should work though: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/27630247/6309. Or try https://github.com/lzrski/npm-git-install

Comment: The problem here is when I used `npm i --save Nodonisko/ionic-cache#pull/43/head`,it removes `dist` folder inside the `node_modules/ionic-cache`.Then no api details for the package and not working?

Comment: @Sampath That I don't know: your edit describes well the problem at hand.